# Real sleepmode WITHOUT hibernation

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, mac-mini

As the most people, I also googled after setting the hibernatemode, and found the following command:

```
sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 0
```

... which should enable the RAM-only sleep mode. I also deleted the sleep image, but the result is not that what I expect.

Hardware config:
Apple Mac mini

- Intel i5 (GPU: HD4000)
- HDD: 500 GB (5400RPM)
- RAM: 4GB

If I put my machine into sleep mode by choosing the Sleep Button after the power button is pressed. It goes into sleep mode in couple of second. OK. If I wake it up, it returns in couple of seconds. Still OK... BUT:

- if I let my machine for some hours in sleep mode, it turns into hibernation, which is both unnecessary and slow with a HDD 5400RPM. And because of that if I turn on my machine, it takes about 1-2 minutes to come back.

**How to turn out hibernation FULLY?** - i really don't need power failure safety feature for a desktop configuration.

Comment: There is a `pmset -a standby` option that switches from sleep to hibernation after a specified amount of time, however the manpage also claims that "standby only works if hibernation is turned on to hibernatemode 3 or 25".

Comment: Thanx ;) that's almost the solution, but I'll research later further in the man page, because if I'd set the standby timer to enormous amount of time, than it needs almost infinite time to get into the hibernation mode.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#power management settings
pmset -g | grep hibernatemode

#remove forcefully
sudo rm -f /var/vm/sleepimage

#0 means normal sleep and is the default for desktops
sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 0   

#1 means hibernate mode and is the default for older portables (pre 2005)
sudo pmset hibernatemode 1 

#3 means safe sleep and is the default for portables made after 2005
sudo pmset hibernatemode 3  

#25 is the same as hibernate mode, but is the setting used for newer (post 2005) Mac portables
sudo pmset hibernatemode 25
```

Comment: Thanks for your instructions, Andy! Unfortunately I already sold my Mac, so I cannot try it out, but I rated your answer up.